# What is the best .NET Micro Framework dev board, for under US$300?

Tags: .net, embedded, robotics, .net-micro-framework

I'm looking for a relativity cheap .NET Micro Framework development board for use on a personal robotics project. I'd don't need much for I/O, but I want at least one serial port and one Ethernet port.

I would prefer not to have to spend more than US$300 on the board, but if there is an obvious reason to get a better one I'm flexible.

Currently I'm looking at [this device from SJJ Embedded Micro Solutions](http://www.sjjmicro.com/EDK.html). Has anyone had experience with this device?

Comment: For more on this topic: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNETMicroFrameworkHardwareForSoftwarePeople.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two different boards that I have been researching. Both of these are around $100.00
 and are meant for the hobbyist. Neither of these boards has ethernet on the board, but is relatively easy to add by adding an external ethernet module

[MeridianP](http://devicesolutions.net/Products/MeridianP.aspx)
[USBizi](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/113)
[USBizi TCP/IP and Ethernet support](http://www.microframeworkprojects.com/project/30)

Answer (score 18):

[Netduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netduino) looks very cool. And only US$30.

The *Plus* version has Ethernet.

Answer (score 5):

**[FEZ](https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/category/274)** has some now generics for sale from 29.00 USD + shipping.

Starting from a 74 MHz ARM development board with Arduino-compatible connectors + a lot more I/O.

- It has open source firmware and fully supports the .NET micro framework as well as a JTAG connector to use for everything else.
- Supports runtime debugging (breakpoints, variable inspection, stepping, etc.)
- Uses Visual C# 2010 Express Edition for development.
- Supports networking with Ethernet shield.

On the same site there is a more complex development board - FEZ Cobra -  which has an onboard Ethernet connector for ~150 USD.

Answer (score 3):

I have not had experience with the SJJ Embedded board, but I might just have to give it a shot.

I'm working on a robotics project as a hobby, and I'm currently prototyping with [Lego Mindstorms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms) and the Robotics SDK from Microsoft. I had planned on swapping to an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) which uses a C-like programming language and weighs in at around US$30 assembled.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the GHI family of boards/devices. They start at $24.95 for the FEZ Panda and goes all the way to $399 for the ChipworkX development kit

http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog

They are also the first out with Gadgeteer  HW

Answer (score 1):

Soon, the Microsoft Gadgeteer will be produced.

See this link for more info:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gadgeteer/default.aspx

[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Clint/NET-Gadgeteer) is a Channel9 video that shows you how to use VS2010 to create an embedded application. It is due to release in Spring of 2011...